# How to use extensions in Postgres installed with Homebrew on Mac OSX

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I'd like to use the [SPI extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/contrib-spi.html) in Postgres 10.2, which I installed with Homebrew. However,

```
CREATE EXTENSION spi;
```

fails with

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/spi.control": No such file or directory
```

Looking inside that `extension` directory, I see many extensions, but not SPI. The Postgres [documentation mentions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/contrib.html) that extensions would reside in a `contrib` directory of the distribution and that you can then build them individually, but I can't seem to find this directory anywhere. Any idea how I can obtain and install the SPI module?

Comment: In Linux you need to install an additional packaged, e.g. `yum install postgresql-contrig` - maybe you need to do something similar on OSX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-spi.html

> Each of the groups of functions described below is provided as a
>   separately-installable extension.

so you check and try:

```
t=# select * from pg_available_extensions where name in ('refint','timetravel','autoinc','insert_username','moddatetime');
      name       | default_version | installed_version |                           comment
-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 moddatetime     | 1.0             |                   | functions for tracking last modification time
 autoinc         | 1.0             |                   | functions for autoincrementing fields
 insert_username | 1.0             |                   | functions for tracking who changed a table
 timetravel      | 1.0             |                   | functions for implementing time travel
 refint          | 1.0             |                   | functions for implementing referential integrity (obsolete)
(5 rows)

t=# create extension refint ;
CREATE EXTENSION
t=# create extension timetravel;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

and so on...